# How can I run an application on my PC but isolated and portable so I can switch PCs when needed

Tags: linux, virtualbox, android

I was looking at dongle mini PCs. I can't seem to find much information on them. What I would like to do is plug in a dongle PC and run an application on it. It would be perfect if it opens up a window kinda like remote desktop or a virtual machine except it would have its own CPU and memory. One of the products I was looking at can be found here: http://cloudnetgo.manufacturer.globalsources.com/si/6008845181547/pdtl/Mini-PC/1113491122/Factory-Price-Android-4.4.2-Cortex-A9-Up-to-1.8GHz.htm.

Someone suggested using virtualbox. But according to https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=14607 it requires virtualbox to be installed on the PC. I am looking for a solution where I can plug something in the USB and run an application in its own environment. Network connectivity would be useful so its not 100% isolated or secure. But for the most part will serve my purposes.

I can put an OS on a flash drive and boot from that but it is a hassle and I would prefer a plug and play solution.

It can run linux or android.

Comment: Instead of posting the same question again, please request your original to be reopened.

Comment: How do I do that?  They told me to reword my question, so I did.  But then I got no respons.  No one said "bad, try again."  No one said "Good" and reopened it.  Basically no one said anything at all except you and I followed the instruction I was given.

Comment: Here ya go, this'll help: http://superuser.com/help/reopen-questions Short version: after editing it (as you did), flag a mod and request it be reopened. I also voted to reopen you original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the portable Version of Virtualbox

http://www.vbox.me/

Comment: But this requires virtual box to be installed on the PC according to a forum post on thier site.  Unless you know of a way to have it run on the stick itself.